# Multiple slugs in WP post

Tags: wordpress, url, blogs

I am currently working on a blog section of a website that's powered by wordpress.

Currently post are defaulted to /blog/$postname%

however we have a select few post that do not need to be /blog/ they should be /news/%postname%

is it possible to do this in WP?

Also if it helps I am using CPT UI to make a custom post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the base url for just a few posts but you can create a separate post type for the ones you want to be different. Using CPTUI you can set their base to be /news. In the CPTUI admin just set "Has Archive" to true and putting "news" in the input for the slug to use.

Comment: Can you select my answer?